# How could I convert these foreach loops into a LINQ-expression?

Tags: c#, linq

I used ReSharper to inspect the code issues in my project and it notified me that the following loop could be converted into a LINQ-expression:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
{
    { "400", new[] { "12345", "54321", "51423" } },
    { "500", new[] { "67890", "09876", "63727" } },
    { "600", new[] { "41713", "98234", "96547" } },
    { "700", new[] { "00000", "67990", "83752" } }
};

// ...

var targetValue = "41713";
foreach (string group in dictionary.Keys)
{
    foreach (string name in dictionary[group])
    {
        if (name == targetValue)
            return group;
    }
}
return "User";
```

The loop basically checks the dictionary's values (string arrays) to see if `targetValue` belongs to any of them and returns the key of that array if found inside.

I tried doing the following, but clearly it just returns the value inside if its value is equivalent to `targetValue`.

```
var r = dictionary
        .SelectMany(t => t.Value)
        .FirstOrDefault(t => t == targetValue);
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter My bad, accidentally wrote ```dictionary``` instead of ```dictionary.Keys```

Comment: If ReSharper notified you that the loop can be converted to LINQ, it can also do that for you.

Comment: @svick I see, I didn't notice that before! Unfortunately ReSharper only converted the inner ```foreach```.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to get the first key in the dictionary which `string[]`-value contains a given value?

```
var pairs = dictionary.Where(kv => kv.Value.Contains(myValue));
if (pairs.Any())
{
    string group = pairs.First().Key;
}
```

or less readable but a little bit more efficient since it executes the query only once:

```
var pair = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(kv => kv.Value.Contains(myValue));
if (!pair.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<string, string[]>)))
{
    string group = pair.Key;
}
```

---

last but not least another approach which is my favorite and also uses the `"User"`-default:

```
string group = dictionary.Where(kv => kv.Value.Contains(myValue))
    .Select(kv=> kv.Key)
    .DefaultIfEmpty("User")
    .First();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I used the second one. I'll update my question with my final code in a moment.

Comment: @GrawCube: i have added another approach which is my favorite. It also takes your `"User"` requiremenet into account.

Comment: The last one seems to be slightly faster than the other two (59ms vs 85ms and 95ms when ran 1000000 times). I'll change to that one!

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var r = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(
    x => x.Value.FirstOrDefault(y => y == myValue) != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also get the desired value back or null if it does not exist:

EDIT:

```
var result = dictionary.SkipWhile(n => !n.Value.Contains(myValue)).FirstOrDefault().Key;
//another way to get the key
//var result = dictionary.SingleOrDefault(n => n.Value.Contains(myValue)).Key;
if (result != null)
{
   //do whatever with the result variable here
}
```

Comment: He wants the key of the dictionary. It's difficult if you throw away it and only have the value now which is also the same value as he already had.